# How to copy all changes from the remote origin master branch to a new branch on local by discarding all changes of it

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a local master branch with 5 commits ahead of remote origin master. I want to create a new branch 'fresh-master' on my local with discarding all changes in my local master branch.  and copy exact same code of remote origin master. While I want to keep the changes in the local master.
How should I do it?
I have created a new branch by `git branch fresh-master` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git fetch
git branch fresh-master origin/master
```

will create a new `fresh-master` branch from the remote state of the branch, without any impact on the already existing `master`.

The new branch will *not* contain `master` recent changes (your recent unpushed commits).

Comment: Please explain more because I don't want to lose the changes which I made in my local master branch.

Comment: Is this also copy the changes of master branch made by me into this new branch  fresh-master. which I don't want?

Comment: @Asis This doesn't impact your other branches at all. It creates a new one pointing at the same commit `origin/master` does. The new branch will *not* contain your local master new changes. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

RomainValeri's answer is mostly correct, but doesn't account for the fact that you said you've already created the new branch.  In that case, the easiest thing to do is

```
git checkout fresh_master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

You may also want to set origin/master up as the upstream branch for fresh_master.

```
git branch -u origin/master
```

*However*, it might get confusing having two branches tracking the same remote branch; it is in some ways more straightforward if you instead create a new branch at your local master, and then simply reset `master` to `origin/master` preserving the normal tracking relationships.

Comment: I think I see your point, it can be a misunderstanding on my part indeed. I might have been thrown off by the statement "I want to create a new branch 'fresh-master'", which I took at face value.